# Separate Cookie expiration for Identity Server and ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I currently have a working Identity Server 4 instance that is used to secure an API accessed by native mobile applications (iOS and Android). For these mobile applications we require the sign out process to be a case of removing the tokens received from Identity Server (e.g. no round trip to the Identity Server).

The issue we face at present with the above is that when the user signs out and we immediately attempt to sign in again, the browser "thinks" the user is already authenticated, due to the presence of the Identity Server Auth cookie from the first sign in.

Our Identity Server configuration at present uses Asp.Net Core Identity and the [Quickstart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) and I have been able to remedy this situation by changing the expiry time of the ASP.NET Core Identity cookie to 1 second as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<UserEntity, ApplicationRoleEntity>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
});
```

Because the Auth cookie is now expired after a second, when the user signs out of the Native app and immediately attempts sign in again, they are presented with the Identity Server login UI and login works as expected.

The change above however obviously has an impact on the use of the Quickstart UI itself when used in a browser (not as part of sign in), as when the cookie expires after a second the user is immediately logged out of the quick start application.

What I am hoping to achieve here is to perhaps separate the ASP.Net Core Identity cookie from the Auth Cookie used by Identity Server - basically so that the Native App can continue to function as is (with an Identity Server Auth cookie that is invalid immediately invalid after sign in, because at this point we have our tokens) but that the user can use the quickstart UI in the browser without their cookie for that app being immediately expired.

## Update 30th Oct 2018 - Proposed Solution

Having reviewed my original post, the simplest way to summarise this requirement is that when signing in via the native application that I require the user to always have to go though the sign in process, even if the browser has a valid authentication cookie for the identity server. This means that the sign out process can simply be a removal of locally stored tokens as when the user attempts to sign back in again they will go through the sign in process again.

I now have a solution which seems to work for my requirements, which involved creating a CookieEvents class for the application cookie used by ASP.NET Core Identity and Identity Server. This is setup as follows in startup.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.EventsType = typeof(CookieEvents);
});
```

In the CookieEvents class I add a new item to the AuthenticationItems.Items dictionary when the signing in event occurs for the authorize endpoint. On future sign in requests to the authorize endpoint from the native mobile application (which I identify using the client_id from the query string in ValidatePrincipal of CookieEvents) I then check for the presence of the item added to the cookie and if found, the principal is rejected, which forces the user to go through the login process again, even if the browser used for the login has a valid authentication cookie. Example of the CookieEvents class below (private methods removed for brevity)

```
public override Task SigningIn(CookieSigningInContext context)
{
    if (IsRequestToAuthorizeEndpoint(context.Request) &&
    !context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("signed-in"))
    {
        context.Properties.Items.Add("signed-in", "true");
    }

    return base.SigningIn(context);
}

public override Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext 
context)
{
    if (IsNativeAppSignIn(context.Request) &&
        context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("signed-in"))
    {
        context.RejectPrincipal();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    return base.ValidatePrincipal(context);
}
```

In testing this appears to work well and also means that if the user is using the actual UI in a browser they are now no longer instantly signed out as the 1 second expiry is no longer in place.

Are there any obvious pitfalls to this approach as a solution to always wanting the user to go through the sign in flow when logging in from the native app, even if their browser has an authentication cookie?

Comment: The sign out process involves invalidating the client's security token and expiring the auth cookie, which requires a roundtrip to the server to achieve. It sounds like what you're doing is some thing like returning a login view directly after logging out, rather than issuing a redirect, which would be sufficient to expire the cookie. Setting the timeout to 1 second effectively makes the user always in a perpetual state of being "logged out", so it's not really a fix for your issue. It's just borking your app in a way that happens to make something that's broken appear to work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I understand that the sign out from IdentityServer requires a round trip. Effectively what I am saying above is that I have no requirement for the user to remain signed into the Identity Server once the initial login and Token exchange is done. The round trip sign out from a native mobile application offers a terrible user experience and that is something I want to avoid, hence wanting my native app signout to be a case of simply removing the locally stored tokens retrieved from the Identity Server at login.

Comment: But that's not how it works. It's not a single point in time event. There's on-going communication between IdentityServer and your client app. Otherwise, it wouldn't be able to communicate events such as an actual intentional logout to clients.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - You refer to "Ongoing Communication" - what ongoing communication with the native app is there going to be?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Just to be clear, in case you are referring to federated sign out, that is not what I am looking for, I have no requirement at this stage for federated signout. The Identity Server docs state "Signing out of IdentityServer is as simple as removing the authentication cookie, but for doing a complete federated sign-out, we must consider signing the user out of the client applications (and maybe even up-stream identity providers) as well." which suggests to me that for the type of sign out I am interested in that the auth token expiring should achieve the goal.